# AngularJS Unit Test Array with Karma

Tags: arrays, angularjs, unit-testing

I created an app of a calendar and I am trying to create a unit test to show where Jan 1, 2016 will show up on the calendar's array which should be at

> $scope.weeks[0][5]

. However, when I test my array I keep getting an undefined on the first element on the array.

Here is the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my unit test code:

```
describe('correctDate', function(){
    var $scope, ctrl;
    beforeEach(module("calendarDemoApp"));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('MonthCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
        $scope.date.month = 0;
        $scope.date.day = 1;
        $scope.date.year = 2016;
        $scope.$apply();
    }));
    fit('should be the 5th element in array', function(){
        expect($scope.date.day).toBe($scope.weeks[0][5].day);
        expect($scope.date.month).toBe($scope.weeks[0][5].month);
        expect($scope.date.year).toBe($scope.weeks[0][5].year);
    });
});
```

Here is the code from my app:

```
angular.module('calendarDemoApp', [])
    .controller('MonthCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.$watch('date', function(newDate){
            var range = CalendarRange.getMonthlyRange(new Date(newDate.year, newDate.month, 1));
            var totalWeeks = range.days.length/7;           
            var weeks = [];
            for(i=0; i<totalWeeks; i++){
                weeks[i] = [];
                for(j=0; j<7; j++){
                    weeks[i].push(range.days[j+(i*7)]);
                }
            }
            $scope.weeks = weeks;
        }, true);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe('correctDate', function(){
    var $scope, ctrl;
    beforeEach(module("calendarDemoApp"));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('MonthCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
        $scope.date.month = 0;
        $scope.date.day = 1;
        $scope.date.year = 2016;
        $scope.$apply();
    }));
    fit('should be the 5th element in array', function(){
        expect($scope.date.day).toBe($scope.weeks[0][5].day);
        expect($scope.date.month).toBe($scope.weeks[0][5].month);
        expect($scope.date.year).toBe($scope.weeks[0][5].year);
    });
});
```

Forgot to add $scope.$apply() for the $watch to fire.
Also had my parameters in the wrong order. 
Had this:

> var range = CalendarRange.getMonthlyRange(new Date(newDate.month,
>   newDate.year, 1));

When it should have been this:

> var range = CalendarRange.getMonthlyRange(new Date(newDate.year,
>   newDate.month, 1));

It set the year to a month of 1 and then a month of 2016. Giving me this calculation: 2016/12 = 168; 1900+168 = 2068.